# Are there unwanted effects to simmering vegetables for days?

Tags: food-science, vegetables, cooking-time, stock, broth

Simply put, will continuously simmering vegetables for days, even up to a week or two, in a perpetual stock lead to unexpected or unwanted results?

Since even the longest stock recipes I know don't take more than a day to make, I assume flavour extraction will stop after a few hours but does cooking veggies beyond that point generate off-flavours?

I've also looked up safety concerns of perpetual broths; in this case, since it's a vegetarian one consistently kept at a simmer to which I will regularly add boiling water, I don't think it will be an issue. I'm still new to food-science though so I might have missed something there.

*Some answers, for example [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/86691/73864) by [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/29537/barbecue) or [that one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/23831/73864) by [jeabp](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/10113/jeabp), partly answer this question, however, I don't think it's specific enough to render this one a duplicate.*

Comment: What different answer do you expect? It's already mentioned in the linked questions: "I think the issue is that there's a limited amount of the aromatic compounds which produce the desired flavor, and over time, these tend to evaporate." so why simmer further?

Comment: To me, this is a duplicate...any aspect that does not cover (will it lead to unwanted results) is probably a matter of opinion.

Comment: @moscafj That question does say "I'm asking explicitly about one unchanged stock: a pot of bones in water, optionally some spices and mirepoix" whereas mine is about a perpetual vegetable stock and the effects of simmering for a long period of time, not how long to simmer.

Comment: @Halhex, I hear you, but the first answer pretty much covers your issue.

Comment: @Luciano That answer does mention the loss of flavour over time, however, it does not talk about possible adverse effects of keeping it on a simmer for longer, such as unwanted flavours.

Comment: @moscafj If the answer to my question is no, except for loss of flavour then I agree with you. But since the question wasn't about a perpetual stock like mine I am left to wonder if there are other effects and other answers. In that sense, even if the other answer also answers this question, I don't think the questions are duplicates.

Comment: Both perpetual stock and unchanged stock are answered in the duplicate. Simmer for days: loss of flavor. Refresh ingredients: stock keeps going.